# Code for a repeated measures, Poisson Regression in R?

Tags: r, offset, lme4, poisson

I am trying to run a model that follows a Poisson distribution and a log link with repeated measures. The subjects are states and each year I have recorded an outcome, which is a count. Lets pretend that its number of hotdogs made. I also need to use an offset for the state population, because I want the number of hotdogs made per year per million people.

I have been looking everywhere but can't find the right code.

I need this to be done in R--I know how to do it in SAS--just use proc genmod, the repeated measures statement, and offset statement, and note the correlation structure. But I can't figure it out here.

I have tried these but it doesnt work:

```
fm1 <- gls(hotdogs ~ Unemploy + Ketchup, family=poisson(link = log), offset= lnpop, data=LSss,
           correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | stateID))

glmmPQL(hotdogs ~ Unemploy + Ketchup, ~1 | StateID, family = poisson(link = "log"), offset=lnpop,
    data = LSss)
```

Comment: I assume you mean SAS, not Stata

Comment: Yes, in SAS, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lme4` or `gamlss`. For example:

```
lme4::glmer(hotdogs ~ offset(log(pop)) + Unemploy + Ketchup + (1|stateID),
            family = poisson, data = LSss)
```

or

```r
gamlss::gamlss(hotdogs ~ offset(log(pop)) + Unemploy + Ketchup + random(stateID),
               family = PO(), data = LSss)
```

This assumes that `pop` is a column in the data `LSss` like the response and the predictors.

Comment: What about specifying the correlation structure?

Comment: Also thank you! This is at least I think most of the way there!

Comment: Doesn't including `stateID` as a random effect induce the correlation structure you want?

Comment: is there anyway to do this with GEE?

Comment: Not sure. These are the two ways I know how to fit a model of this kind. If you have more specific requirements, you might get more informative answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.